# add mtrr entry in linux with C code

Tags: c, linux, memory, assembly, kernel

I am trying to add an entry to MTRR to mark a memory region as write combining, but the kernel does not accepts my call. It returns EINVAL errno. What could be the problem? I have tried everything but have no luck. Here is the code and the output after running it:

```
   #define NUM_ELTS        (1024*64)

    struct mtrr_sentry sentry;

    void register_wc(uint *addr);

    void register_wc(uint *addr) {
        int fd,ret;
        int aux1,aux2;
        int page_size;

        sentry.base=(ulong) addr;
        sentry.size=NUM_ELTS;
        sentry.type=MTRR_TYPE_WRCOMB;

        page_size=getpagesize();
        aux1=sentry.base & (page_size - 1);
        aux2=sentry.size & (page_size - 1);

        printf("aux1=%d, aux2=%d, base=%d, size=%d, type=%d\n",aux1,aux2,sentry.base,sentry.size,sentry.type);

        fd=open("/proc/mtrr",O_WRONLY); if (fd==-1) { perror("open()"); exit(2); }
        printf("fd=%d\n",fd);
        ret=ioctl(fd,MTRRIOC_ADD_ENTRY,&sentry); if (ret==-1) { perror("ioctl()"); exit(3); }
        sleep(10);
        close(fd);
    }
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ulong size;
    uint *data;

    size=sizeof(uint)*NUM_ELTS;

    data=(uint*) memalign(4096,size);   if (!data) { exit(1); }
    printf("data address is %d, PAGE_SIZE=%d\n",data,getpagesize());
    register_wc(data);
}
```

The output produced by the program is:

```
data address is -1420279808, PAGE_SIZE=4096
aux1=0, aux2=0, base=-1420279808, size=65536, type=1
fd=3
ioctl(): Invalid argument
```

The code is copied (almost) from /usr/src/linux/Documentation/x86/mtrr.txt

Answer (score 2):

The base address you pass to `MTRRIOC_ADD_ENTRY` must be a **physical** address. It looks like you're passing in a **logical** address to a block of memory you just allocated, which doesn't make any sense. MTRRs are used to control access to memory-mapped hardware, not to RAM.

Comment: then how do I convert the logical address returned from memalign() in main() function to the physiscal address?

Comment: You can't. It doesn't have a fixed physical address. In any case, the memory returned by `memalign()` is not device memory, so turning on write combining really doesn't make sense.

Comment: Are you are saying is that the MTRR driver in Linux kernel is useless ? Then how do you mark a memory block as write combining? I could do it writing directly to the processor, but I saw linux kernel has an api for this, but aparently it doesn't work well, or I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Like the README says, and like I said earlier, it's for controlling access to device memory like video cards. Far from useless, just not useful **to you**.

Comment: just because video cards use it doesn't mean WC memory is for devices only. You can get up to 7x speed up in your application if you use WC, all those MOVNTQA instructions will work as they were designed to work, i.e not polluting the cache.

Answer (score 0):

What @duskwulf said.

You haven't defined

```
struct mtrr_sentry sentry
```

and the members don't have addresses.

EDIT: I think you want to add the definition of mtrr_sentry.

```
#include <asm/mtrr.h>
```

Comment: yes, I did, I just didn't include header because the webiste has problems when you insert '#' character